# Substring extract from database file paths

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I need to extract a substring from list of paths in a T-sql query.. for example I need to get the paths of database files.. if I use the below query...

```
Select distinct (physical_name) from sys.master_files
```

I just want to have database file paths without.. the file name..ie...

```
C:\Data\Microsoft instead of C:\Data\Microsoft\db1.mdf
C:\Data\Microsoft instead of C:\Data\Microsoft\db2.mdf
D:\Log\Microsoft instead of D:\Log\Microsoft\db1.ldf
D:\Log\Microsoft instead of D:\Log\Microsoft\db2.ldf..
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Have you tried anything? E.g. using functions SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because I could not resist:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

LEFT(physical_name, LEN(physical_name) - CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(physical_name))) as physical_path

FROM sys.master_files
```

It finds the position of last '\' in the path using CHARINDEX and reverse string, and then cuts everything up to that point via LEFT.

Comment: Yeah.. I tried.. but I am not a sql developer though...thanks....yuriy...it helped me alot..